# sony w8 with Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, adb

I want to test my programs on my Sony W8 device , not on emulator. I have tried everything but am not able to.

Sony W8 is not on the list and keeps asking for "Choose a running android 2.1 device".

I have enabled the USB debugging mode, installed the Sony PC companion as well. Please help.

Comment: try running adb with admin rights in your android SDK install directory, the command adb devices under the platform-tools directory should show any recognized devices

Comment: adb devices not recognizing any .. how to run adb with admin rights ?

Comment: you can right click adb and "run as administrator" or just be logged in as an administrator...best bet is you don't have the right driver installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed an app : Easytether .. It solve the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

download the driver from Sony website and install it manually on your computer, If does not work place the drviver folder in eclipse sdk

Comment: download driver from sony website for your mobile phone and manually install it

Answer (score 0):

You probly do not have installed the correct drivers. You could try [these](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/update/drivers/mobile-phone/sony/w8-walkman-phone/sub-models/)

Comment: You need the drivers to test an aplication on your device